# "AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM" with nothing else

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

For some reason, LogCat doesn't report any stack traces anymore on crashes. Instead, I only get the following info:

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40dd3960)
```

This is really weird because I've been working on the very same project for three months, and only recently (two, three days ago) the stack traces stopped showing. What could cause this? How can I get it to show stack traces again?

Comment: Check if you accidentally applied a filter to the logcat or changed some other setting.

Comment: I am having the same issue. It started when I updated the Google Analytics library to version 7.5, and implicitly added multidex support to the app. ga_reportUncaughtExceptions=false in my analytics.xml file

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I experienced the same problem. After upgrading Google Analytics to version 7 (or 7.3, I do not remember), my app always closes without any logcat messages when encountering an error.

It turns out that it happens if I enable both a custom catch-all-exception handler (`Thread#setUncaughtExceptionHandler`) and the report crash feature in Google Analytics.

When I disable one of them, the logcat displays the stack trace again.

Answer (score 14):

Very simple to fix.

### Just change from

```
...
Tracker tracker; // from Google Analytics
...
tracker = analytics.newTracker(getStringRes(R.string.ga_tracker));
tracker.enableExceptionReporting(true); // this is the cause
```

### To:

```
tracker.enableExceptionReporting(false);
```

Now, it's back to normal.

Comment: In wherever you defined Google Analytics. Usually in your application level.

Comment: That was like a magic for me. There was one hidden NPE that only came to log-cat after i disabled Analytics exception reporting as you suggested. Its weird because if its trying to report errors it should get atleast visible on Google analytics panel but its neither on Log cat nor on Google Analytics. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if any of the operations are left unimplemented
like if (Todo is written inside the overridden methods)
so after implementing these all the methods this error is gone