# Possible GridView Bug

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, gridview

I have implemented a `GridView` by following [this guide](http://www.mhjaso.com/blog/gridviews-en-android/).
It works perfectly.

The problems comes when I call the `GridView` Fragment from the `NavigationDrawer`.
When I push the button of the NavDrawer, the app freezes and I get these messages from the Android Monitor:

```
11-03 14:08:53.349 15968-15968/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM 
11-03 14:08:53.349 15968-15968/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4208a898)
```

The app will stay frozen until I kill it.
Any idea?

More info:

I call the Fragment whis way:

```
Fragment frag = new Grid_Fragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, frag).commit();
```

Full log:

```
11-03 14:24:46.389 26230-26230/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
11-03 14:24:46.669 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
11-03 14:24:46.669 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
11-03 14:24:46.679 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 17126: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
11-03 14:24:46.679 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
11-03 14:24:46.679 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
11-03 14:24:46.679 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 17130: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
11-03 14:24:46.679 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
11-03 14:24:46.889 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware I/AMain: onResume
11-03 14:24:47.009 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno.so
11-03 14:24:47.009 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so
11-03 14:24:47.009 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
11-03 14:24:47.129 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:381>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_3.2_RB2.04.03.00.129.098_msm8226_JB_3.2_RB2__release_AU ()
11-03 14:24:47.129 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware I/Adreno-EGL: OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 20.00.08
11-03 14:24:47.129 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware I/Adreno-EGL: Build Date: 03/04/14 Tue
11-03 14:24:47.129 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware I/Adreno-EGL: Local Branch: 
11-03 14:24:47.129 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware I/Adreno-EGL: Remote Branch: quic/jb_3.2_rb2.32
11-03 14:24:47.129 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware I/Adreno-EGL: Local Patches: NONE
11-03 14:24:47.129 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware I/Adreno-EGL: Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_3.2_RB2.04.03.00.129.098 +  NOTHING
11-03 14:24:47.249 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
11-03 14:24:47.389 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware I/AMain: onResume
11-03 14:24:48.909 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
11-03 14:24:48.909 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 668: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
11-03 14:24:48.909 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
11-03 14:24:48.909 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
11-03 14:24:48.909 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 690: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
11-03 14:24:48.909 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
11-03 14:24:49.019 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setLocalOnly, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
11-03 14:24:49.019 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 252: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setLocalOnly (Z)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
11-03 14:24:49.019 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x00c2
11-03 14:24:49.019 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.AppOpsManager.checkPackage, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
11-03 14:24:49.019 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 130: Landroid/app/AppOpsManager;.checkPackage (ILjava/lang/String;)V
11-03 14:24:49.019 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0010
11-03 14:24:49.019 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzh
11-03 14:24:49.019 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 593: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
11-03 14:24:49.019 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
11-03 14:24:49.019 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware I/GAv4: Google Analytics 7.8.95 is starting up. To enable debug logging on a device run:
11-03 14:24:49.019 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware I/GAv4:   adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
11-03 14:24:49.019 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware I/GAv4:   adb logcat -s GAv4
11-03 14:24:49.039 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware W/GAv4: AnalyticsReceiver is not registered or is disabled. Register the receiver for reliable dispatching on non-Google Play devices. See http://goo.gl/8Rd3yj for instructions.
11-03 14:24:49.049 26230-26341/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware W/GAv4: AnalyticsService not registered in the app manifest. Hits might not be delivered reliably. See http://goo.gl/8Rd3yj for instructions.
11-03 14:24:49.049 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware I/AMain: connectBleService
11-03 14:24:52.819 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-03 14:24:52.819 26230-26230/com.daswaretech.apps.dasware W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4208a898)
```

Comment: Can you post some more lines of log? It is important to find the uncaught exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should be able to see the Error level exception log causing the issue.

Check if you accidentaly enabled a catch-all-exception handler:

["AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM" with nothing else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31074585/androidruntime-shutting-down-vm-with-nothing-else)

Without a proper exception log it's too much guessing (maybe the R.id.content_frame is not defined in the XML layout?)

Comment: The catch-all-exception handler was the problem with not seeing the trace. Finally not an Android bug with the GridView. i will keep working.