# Why Android crashes instead of showing the error in debug mode

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, reflection

**At first, my story:**

So after a while, I have found the reason which causes the crashing of my app in debug mode!!
I used `replace` command to replace a fragment with another one, but it crashes and exits from debug mode. In the same sample, it works fine and finally, I got the problem that was about my forgetfulness about the implementation of its listener. Though, in the code, there was a `throw` command for unimplementation!

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}
```

In **Android Monitor** when the crash happens, only these lines are appended:

> 07-05 08:05:54.797 6171-6171/com.shoniz.saledistributemobility
>   D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>
> 07-05 08:05:54.799    6171-6171/com.shoniz.saledistributemobility
>   I/art: System.exit    called, status: 2
>
> 07-05 08:05:54.799    6171-6171/com.shoniz.saledistributemobility
>   I/AndroidRuntime: VM    exiting with result code 2, cleanup skipped.
>
> 07-05 08:05:54.801    1303-1576/system_process D/GraphicsStats: Buffer
>   count: 3

**Now my question**

Is there any way to force Android Studio to stop running and show the reason of the crash to save our time?! Something like a work that **Visual Studio** does.

Answer (score 1):

use  fabric crash analytic tool https://try.crashlytics.com/
you will get all error in mail or dashboard with logcat .if you cant get error in logcat you will get in crashlytics dash board.only internet should be on

Comment: I apply all stages in your solution. But I don't know how can I see the errors?

Comment: if succefully configure then do 1 crash and and login go to crash analystic and go to dashboard you will get all crash with mobile model number

Answer (score 1):

it crashes, because you throw an `Exception`, which then is not being handled with `try` / `catch`. the log which you've pasted is probably not "the interesting part" of it, at least cannot tell too much from it. added the "reflection" tag to the question, because that is what it is all about...

basically, there are two ways to get there:

```
if (! OnFragmentInteractionListener.class.isAssignableFrom(context)) {
    throw new ReflectiveOperationException(message);
}
```

for testing purposes, it is more convenient to just log the error; as others suggested, those remote "Exceptions" are not necessarily real exceptions - one can log regular errors declared as a custom `Exception` to [Firebase Crash Reporting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/) and/or [Crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics) (with no force close in runtime, while not throwing anything).

```
if (! OnFragmentInteractionListener.class.isAssignableFrom(context)) {
    FirebaseCrash.report(new ReflectiveOperationException(message));
    if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {Log.e(LOG_TAG, message);}
    return false;
}
```

Comment: My main problem is not how prevent crash the app, but how to know which command has an error. In my case I didn't know there is a throw in my code which causes the problem and it takes a time to found it by test line by line of code

Comment: @SiamakFerdos as soon as one calls to `throw` one has to handle the thrown `Exception` ...verbose logging in debug mode is way better for testing, because something non-functional which keeps running (or running into an error) is still better than something non-functional which crashes.

Comment: But debugging mode shows nothing about this error at all! The problem is here that debugging mode not works with my sample at all.

Comment: Consider to Android Monitor about the problem of crash too. No error is shown but app crashes in debugging mode

Comment: @SiamakFerdos this might be related https://stackoverflow.com/a/31259916/549372 (maybe search code and libraries once for `setUncaughtExceptionHandler`); while if no Exception is thrown at all, one can still single-step into and/or set conditional breakpoints (in order not to hit "next" too often). is there really nothing red above the "Shutting down VM"? could imagine a framework bug, which should throw an Exception, while it doesn't... installing the SDK sources and single-stepping into would show exactly where it bugs out.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is, that you assume the `Context` to implement `OnFragmentInteractionListener`. You should find out, which instance you receive. This might not be your `Activity` directly, but another context wrapping it.

Throwing this error if your assertions fail is actually fine. It should as well be logged within *Logcat*. Maybe it would be better to use `IllegalArgumentException`, `IllegalStateException` or `AssertionError`.

If you want to log an error only you can use `Log.e(tag, message)` or `Timber.e(message)` when using the [Timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber) logging utility.

Comment: Where should I put `Log` command? My problem was that I didn't know where the problem occurs to handle it.

Comment: If you know it's at the `Exception` you posted, just before throwing it.